# Not able to receive packets using DPDK over vmxnet3

Tags: vmware, dpdk

I have implemented a simple code that sends the packet from one machine to other using DPDK.
When I use E1000E then I am able to receive packets. But when I use vmxnet3 then at the receiver side erroneous packets are received as per ethernet stats. rte_eth_rx_burst() dont receive any packet.
Is there a way to solve this? Why packets are erroneous?

update: vmxnet3 is receiving non DPDK packets correctly but when it comes to DPDK packets sent by our custom generator, it is still categorised as erroneous. Did something changed with respect to security in ESXI and Vcenter? I worked for earlier version of ESXI with vcenter 6+.

[EDIT-1] details shared based on the comment

VMShpere version: 7

1. VMShpere vswitch: connected between only 2 VMs backed as 10Gbps VMXNET3 NIC
2. DPDK verion: 18.11
3. Guest os: Ubuntu 20.04 (tried Ubuntu 16.04 as well)
4. Packet Flow: mac address is changed according to destination VM Setup: VM-1 runs DPDK application is custom packet generator and receptor, and VM-2 runs rx_burst and tx_burst.

Comment: there can multitude of reason, can you please share following information like VMsphere version, Vmsphere switch details connecting to vmxnet3, DPDK version, guest os version, packet mac dest address, vmxnext3 address, dpdk application used, and  running with option `--log-level=pmd,8 and --log-level=8`

Comment: VMShpere version: 7, vswitch is connected between only two VMs backed by 10gbps NIC. DPDK verion used is 18.11, Guest os: Ubuntu 20.04 (tried Ubuntu 16.04 as well), Packet mac address is changed according to destination VM, I verified this using ethernet stats, without correct mac address destination won't show any packet (not even error packets). DPDK application is custom packet generator and receptor. Just used rte_eth_tx_burst after packet formation and rte_eth_rx_burst.

Comment: Thanks @avinashkrc please update the question with above information and remaining information (without DPDK does vmxnet3 packets are received or not? does standard DPDK application like l2fwd/skeleton is able to send and receive? what is result of log-level).

Comment: Hi vipin, l2fwd needs to be fed packets before forwarding it to other, correct me If I am wrong. I didnt check skeleton yet. Rest of the details I updated

Comment: you can always use vdev port like tap, kni or any pcap PMD as second port for testing. Example `examples/l2fwd/build/l2fwd -c 0xf0 --vdev=net_tap0,iface=myetestport -- -p 0x3 -T 1`. Then in another terminal run `ifconfig mytestport up; ping _i mytestport 12.12.12.12.`

Comment: HI @avinashkrc are there any updates?

Comment: I am able to see packet sent and received getting increment. I changed the IP to my vmxnet3 ip as well. But vmxnet3 is not configured to use DPDK, so i dont know how it helps?

Comment: I am not clear with the above statement, my expectation is VMsphere will tell hypervisor to emaulte the nic for guest. Inside the guest one needs to bind with user space driver. Hence it will easier if it s live debug. can we do that?

Comment: sorry I might have misunderstood your commands. Shall I bind DPDK to vmxnet3 and then execute examples/l2fwd/build/l2fwd -c 0xf0 --vdev=net_tap0,iface=mytestport -- -p 0x3 -T 1. Later in another terminal i should execute ifconfig mytestport up; ping -I mytestport 12.12.12.12. Correct me If I am wrong here.  I am not able to understand how pinging 12.12.12.12 will send packets to DPDK bound vmxnet3 because once we bind any nic to DPDK, it loses its ip.

Comment: `-vdev=net_tap0,iface=mytestport` option creates a tap kernel interface in guest os. So the IP address you are configuring lets say `a:b:c::d` fi applied to tap will return the response. Also not if using `l2fwd` you should run with `--no-mac-updating` But your original post was vmxnet32 did not get packets. Hence I am requesting live debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[answer based on the live debug] there is no issue on the DPDK side with either e1000e or vmxnet3 device. Based on the current debug it based on switch on vsphere

Debugging with kernel driver `vmnext3`, shows

1. VM-1 receives and transmit packets
2. VM-2 receives and transmit packets
3. there is a physical interface also connected which forwards packets.
4. set the IP address of VM-1 to '12.12.12.1' and IP address of VM-2 to '12.12.12.2'
5. Run iperf3 between VM-1 and VM-2, `it fails`.
6. debugging with `tcpdump` showcases that VM-1 is not receiving packets from the switch from VM-2. While packets from VM-1 are received.

The same is behaviour with DPDK l2fwd/testpmd/skeleton and even sample application. Hence DPDK 18.11.11 LTS with vmxnet3 has no issues in sending or receiving packets.